# Why would I add a function to an objects prototype rather than add it to the object?

Tags: javascript

Somebody asked me this question and i was a little lost by it.

As this is a Q&A it makes sense to ask here.

Why would I add a function to an objects prototype rather than add it to the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these two objects:

### Object 1

```
var myObject1 = function() {
    this.myProperty = true;
    this.myMethod = function() {
        return this.myProperty;
    };
}
```

### Object 2

```
var myObject2 = function() {
   this.myProperty = true;
}

myObject2.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    return this.myProperty;
};
```

Everytime we do this:

```
var test = new myObject1();
```

myObject1.myMethod also gets created. Where as when we do this:

```
var test = new myObject2();
```

myObject2.myMethod does not have the overhead of needing to be created again because it was added to the prototype chain.

This wouldn't matter for a few instances but in a game, for example, where there could be hundreds of instances this can be quite a performance hit.

---

This net.tutsplus article may explain it better than me http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/prototypes-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: correct answer just because of the explanation :) I was confident this was the answer but having somebody better than you telling you is a nice feeling :p cheers

Answer (score 4):

Because, if you add it to the prototype it will be available on all "instances" of an object. If you add it to the object itself, it will only be available on that single instance.